# how to download All File from Arraylist in android?

Tags: android, arraylist, download

i want to all download video and save in sdcard.i have arraylist in all file.not a single file.how to possible it .please help me.

```
ArrayList<Url_Dto> list = new ArrayList<Url_Dto>();
```

Thanks in advance!!!

what is pass param in DownloadFileFromURL().i used button click event.

```
mainDownloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                            //what is pass param

                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute();
            }
        });
```

may download class in below ::

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

        int count = 0;
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        int myProgress;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressBar progressBar;

        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "params  :::; " + params);
            int count;
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) params[0];
            try {
                // URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URL url = new URL((String) params[1]);
                Log.v("log_tag", "name  ::: " + url);
                name = ((String) params[1]).substring(((String) params[1])
                        .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                Log.v("log_tag", "name Substring ::: " + name);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);
                download = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/download/");
                if (!download.exists()) {
                    download.mkdir();
                }
                String strDownloaDuRL = download + "/" + name;
                Log.v("log_tag", " down url   " + strDownloaDuRL);
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strDownloaDuRL);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    // publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) /
                    // lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    progressBar
                            .setProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.v("log_tag", "progress :: " + values);
            // setting progress percentage
            // pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            Log.v("log", "login  ::: 4::: " + download);
            String videoPath = download + "/" + name;
            String chpName = name;
            Log.v("log_tag", "chpName  ::::" + chpName + "  videoPath "
                    + videoPath);
            db.execSQL("insert into videoStatus (chapterNo,videoPath) values(\""
                    + chpName + "\",\"" + videoPath + "\" )");

        }

    }
```

Comment: just use for loop of arraylist size and put Download Task in this for loop...

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification) provides an idea on http file download. With that idea, you can iterate through all the video URLs in the list.